# How to put several elements on one line using only HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put three elements that contain text on one line using only HTML tags and the style property. One of the elements is a counter that is counting up. Unfortunately the elements are too far from each other in my solution as I am trying to get them to stick together seamlessly. Cold you please help me out?

*FYI: I have read several posts here on SO before posting and tried my best to make a solution below.*

```html
<span style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
<span> There is </span>
<strong><span class="counter" style="font-family:Courier New; style:bold" data-target="100">0</span></strong> 
<span>kg spam.</span>
</span>


<script>
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
for(let n of counters) {
  const updateCount = () => {
    const target = + n.getAttribute('data-target');
    const count = + n.innerText;
    const speed = 5000; // change animation speed here
    const inc = target / speed; 
    if(count < target) {
      n.innerText = Math.ceil(count + inc);
      setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
    } else {
      n.innerText = target;
    }
  }
  updateCount();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `justify-content: space-between;` and adding padding to the left and right of the counter should work:

```html
<span style="display: flex;">
<span>There is </span>
<strong><span class="counter" style="font-family: Courier New; style: bold; padding: 0 0.2em" data-target="100">0</span></strong> 
<span> kg spam.</span>
</span>


<script>
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
for(let n of counters) {
  const updateCount = () => {
    const target = + n.getAttribute('data-target');
    const count = + n.innerText;
    const speed = 5000; // change animation speed here
    const inc = target / speed; 
    if(count < target) {
      n.innerText = Math.ceil(count + inc);
      setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
    } else {
      n.innerText = target;
    }
  }
  updateCount();
}
</script>
```

You might need to tweak the margin size, but this is the best idea I came up with.

Comment: If you add `padding: 0 4px` to `style="font-family:Courier New; style:bold;`, the spacing should look better. Final: `style="font-family:Courier New; style:bold; padding: 0 4px;"`

Comment: Wouldn't using `em` be better because it scales to the text size?

Comment: Thank you for the replies! Do you by any chance know how I put the last spans on a new line if it was needed? Its mainly too look decent for mobile version in case the width is reduced too much.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to form a sentence then you don't need these many `spans` they are all [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements). I think one span is enough:

```html
<style>
  .counter {
    style="font-family:Courier New;"
  }
</style>
<span>
     There is <em class="counter" data-target="100">0</em>kg spam. 
     And <em class="counter" data-target="200">0</em> buns.
</span>



<script>
  const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
  for (let n of counters) {
    const updateCount = () => {
      const target = +n.getAttribute('data-target');
      const count = +n.innerText;
      const speed = 5000; // change animation speed here
      const inc = target / speed;
      if (count < target) {
        n.innerText = Math.ceil(count + inc);
        setTimeout(updateCount, 15);
      } else {
        n.innerText = target;
      }
    }
    updateCount();
  }
</script>
```

If screen width reduces the line will wrap automatically. Same text with 100px wide box wraps perfectly. You don't have to do anything:

```html
<style>
  .counter {
    style="font-family:Courier New;"
  }
  div{
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
</style>
<div><span>
     There is <em class="counter" data-target="100">0</em>kg spam. 
     And <em class="counter" data-target="200">0</em> buns.
</span></div>



<script>
  const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
  for (let n of counters) {
    const updateCount = () => {
      const target = +n.getAttribute('data-target');
      const count = +n.innerText;
      const speed = 5000; // change animation speed here
      const inc = target / speed;
      if (count < target) {
        n.innerText = Math.ceil(count + inc);
        setTimeout(updateCount, 15);
      } else {
        n.innerText = target;
      }
    }
    updateCount();
  }
</script>
```